# I Keep Getting Syntax Error When I Try to Insert Value into a MySql Table

Tags: python, mysql

```
def inserindo_novos_valores_uma_coluna(tabela, coluna, id_user):

    # Conectando ao banco de dados
    banco_inser_dados = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user_name,
        passwd=passwd,
        database=database
    )
    cursor = banco_inser_dados.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM {tabela} WHERE {coluna} = {id_user}")
        comando_sql = f"INSERT INTO {tabela} ({coluna}) VALUES (%s)"
        dados_ = (str(id_user))
        cursor.execute(comando_sql, dados_)
        banco_inser_dados.commit()
    except Exception as InserValue:
        print(InserValue)
        comando_sql = f"INSERT INTO {tabela} ({coluna}) VALUES (%s)"
        dados_ = (str(id_user))
        cursor.execute(comando_sql, dados_)
        banco_inser_dados.commit()
```

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: where is your `tabela` & `coluna` defined in the code

Comment: It should be `dados_ = (str(id_user,),)` with a comma to turn it into an actual tuple because the second argument to `execute` needs to be an `iterable`..

Comment: Your exception handler block appears to be identical to the try block except for the DELETE. I don't get it.

Comment: @AjayA It was a code formatting issue; these variables are passed as function arguments.

Comment: Using dados_ = (str(id_user,),) worked very fine

Comment: Learn how to correctly format your code.

Comment: I'm quite new at python, is there a site or something like that where I can learn how to improve the coding formating and good pratices?